# How to label percentage values inside stacked bar plot using R-base

Tags: r

I am new to R. I would like others to explain to me how to add absolute values inside the individual stacked bars in a consistent way using the basic R plotting function (R base). I tried to plot a stacked bar graph using R base but the values appear in an inconsistent/illogical way in such a way that its supposed to be 100% for each village but they don't sum up to 100%.
Here is the data that am working on:

```
Village      100         200       300  400      500

Male    68.33333    53.33333        70   70 61.66667

Female  31.66667    46.66667        30   30 38.33333
```

In summary, there are five villages and the data showing the head of household interviewed by sex.

I have used the following command towards plotting the graph:

```
barplot(mydata,col=c("yellow","green")
x<-barplot(mydata,col=c("yellow","green")
text(x,mydata,labels=mydata,pos=3,offset=.5)
```

Please help to allocate the correct values in each bar
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site.  As this is more about how to do something in R than the statistics behind it, it is probably better on Stack Overflow.  In the meantime, how does the Village variable fit in - is it shown in your barplot at all?  Secondly, are you interested in possible alternatives to a bar plot (which might mean it stays more of an on-topic for Cross Validated question).

Comment: hmm, definitely a duplicate, can they be merged?

Answer (score 13):

This started as a comment but it seemed unfair to not turn into an answer.  To answer your question (even on Stack Overflow) properly we need to know how "mydata" is structured.  I assumed at first it was a data frame with 5 rows and 2 or 3 columns but in this case your code makes no sense.  However, if this *were* how it is structured here is one way to do what I think you want:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
    row.names =c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
    Male =c(68.33333, 53.33333, 70, 70, 61.66667),
    Female =c(31.66667, 46.66667, 30, 30, 38.33333))

x <- barplot(t(as.matrix(mydata)), col=c("yellow", "green"), 
    legend=TRUE, border=NA, xlim=c(0,8), args.legend=
        list(bty="n", border=NA), 
    ylab="Cumulative percentage", xlab="Village number")
text(x, mydata$Male-10, labels=round(mydata$Male), col="black")
text(x, mydata$Male+10, labels=100-round(mydata$Male))
```

which produces the following:

[image]

An alternative would be to set the y value to 40 for all the male text labels, and 80 for all the females - this would have the advantage of less confusing jitter of the labels, and the disadvantage that the text vertical position is no longer notionally attached to data.

Personally, I don't much like this barplot at all, although there are many far worse crimes against data visualisation than a straightforward bar plot.  Numbers on plots are cluttering and detract from the visual impact of the actual mapping of data to colours, shapes and sizes.  I'd rather a simple dot plot like:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=row.names(mydata), y=Male)) +
  geom_point(size=4) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x="Village number\n", y="Percentage male") +
  ylim(0,100) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=50, linetype=2)
```

which gives

[image]

There is less redundant clutter in the plot, a higher data to ink ratio, etc.  However in the end you need to produce the plot that will mean something for your audience.